# Display an error on STDERR and exit in Perl?

Tags: perl

I currently implement my error display as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
error("Something happened");

sub error {say STDERR "Error: ", shift; and exit 1}
```

I am wondering if a better solution exists.

I don’t want to use `die` because the output with the traceback is sometimes too cryptic for basic users. I want a clean and simple message.

Actually I do the same with

```
sub verb {say STDERR "Info: ", shift;}
sub warning {say STDERR "Warning: ", shift;}
```

Comment: Why you do not use [log4perl](http://search.cpan.org/~mschilli/Log-Log4perl-1.46/lib/Log/Log4perl.pm)?

Comment: @Jens, two reasons: first,  feel `Log4Perl` is much more complicated that just a `say STDERR "something" and exit`, and second, `Log4Perl` is not a core module. People will need to install a module just to display error messages. This sounds a bit too complex and not very [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

Comment: But reinventing the wheel is also no good solution.

Comment: @Jens so can you provide a solution with Log4Perl that does what I need? With `use Log::Log4perl qw(:easy); Log::Log4perl->easy_init($ERROR); ERROR "This gets logged";` I don't get the expected message `Error: This gets logged`

Comment: An exit code of `-1` makes no sense. Use non-negative numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`die` doesn't output a stack trace; it merely displays the line on which `die` is located, and even that can be omitted by ending the message with a line feed.

```
$ perl -e'die "foo\n"'
foo
```

Comment: Actually I love Perl but these very subtle subtleties such as the effect of a `\n` confuses me all the time. Where can I find a nice cheat sheet with all these nice details ?